# I need to write query for numbers of occurance

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, count

```
file_id   status  date_occure
1         1       2013-04-10:3:26
1         2       2013-04-10:3:27
1         3       2013-04-10:3:28
```

only rows whis same file_id and have 3 statuses :1,2,3 whis same date, occured one by one need be to counted as one occure

```
-----------------------------------
1         4       2013-04-10:3:26
rows whis another statuses not be counted
----------------------------------
1         1       2013-04-10:3:26
1         3       2013-04-10:3:27
1         2       2013-04-10:3:28       
also rows ordered by date but statuses no (1->2->3) not be counted
-----------------------------------
```

Table containts many rows, result must by grouped be  `file_id`.

Thanks and Regards

Comment: select count(count_occure) from (select count(status) as count_occure from my_table where status in (1,2,3) group by file_id, date_occure having count(atatus_id)=3)a)  - its non correct

Comment: @user2265127 please update your question with that comment! :)

Comment: What if there are more sequential (1-2-3) occurrences within the same day? Does does count as valid or not?

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem stems from the fact that you want to group by days, but your column `Date_occure` is also storing time. I am not 100% sure of the exact output you require, but this should give you everything you need:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  [File_ID], 
            [Status],
            Date_Occure,
            Occurrences = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status] IN (1, 2, 3) THEN [Status] END) OVER(PARTITION BY [File_ID], CAST(Date_Occure AS DATE)),
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [File_ID], CAST(Date_Occure AS DATE) ORDER BY Date_Occure, [Status] DESC)
    FROM    T
)
SELECT  [File_ID], [Status], Date_Occure, Occurrences
FROM    CTE
WHERE   RowNumber = 1;
```

The key is partitioning by `CAST(Date_Occure AS DATE)` rather than just `date_occure`.

A simplified version would be:

```
SELECT  [File_ID], 
        Date_Occure = MIN(Date_Occure),
        Occurrences = COUNT(CASE WHEN [Status] IN (1, 2, 3) THEN [Status] END)
FROM    T
GROUP BY [File_ID], CAST(Date_Occure AS DATE);
```

**EDIT**

I have just re-read the question and think I now understand the criteria.

If **All** three status (1, 2, 3) have to appear and in order then you can use this:

```
SELECT  [File_ID],
        Date_Occure = MIN(Date_Occure)
FROM    T
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    T T2
            WHERE   T2.[File_ID] = t.[File_ID]
            AND     CAST(T2.Date_Occure AS DATE) = CAST(T.Date_Occure AS DATE)
            AND     T2.[Status] > T.[Status]
            AND     T2.Date_Occure < T.Date_Occure
        )
GROUP BY [File_ID]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN [Status] IN (1, 2, 3) THEN [Status] END) = 3;
```

The `NOT EXISTS` ensures that a record with an out of sequence status does not exists, and the `HAVING` ensures that all 3 status (1, 2, 3) are present.

If you just want all files where all the status are sequential for a particular day then you can use something like this to rank records in order of status, and rank them in order of date and exclude files where there is a mis-match:

```
WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  [File_ID], 
            [Status],
            Date_Occure,
            DateOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [File_ID], CAST(Date_Occure AS DATE) ORDER BY [Status], Date_Occure ASC),
            StatusOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [File_ID], CAST(Date_Occure AS DATE) ORDER BY Date_Occure, [Status] ASC),
            Occurrences = COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY [File_ID], CAST(Date_Occure AS DATE)),
            RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY [File_ID], CAST(Date_Occure AS DATE) ORDER BY Date_Occure, [Status] DESC)
    FROM    T
)
SELECT  [File_ID], [Status], Date_Occure, Occurrences
FROM    CTE
WHERE   RowNumber = 1
AND     NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    CTE T2
            WHERE   T2.[File_ID] = CTE.[File_ID]
            AND     CAST(T2.Date_Occure AS DATE) = CAST(CTE.Date_Occure AS DATE)
            AND     T2.DateOrder != T2.StatusOrder
        );
```

**[Examples on SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e1e79/1)**